# The non-negativity condition of a discretized mean-reverting Heston model with stochastic violatilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I happened to encounter the following discretized mean-reverting Heston model with stochastic volatilities in a paper
$$
P(t) = P(t-1) + v_1(u_1-P(t-1))+\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\cdot \epsilon_1(t) \\
\sigma(t) = \sigma(t-1) + v_2(u_2-\sigma(t-1))+\sqrt{\sigma(t-1)}\cdot \epsilon_2(t)
$$
where $v_1=v_2=0.1,u_1=100,u_2=0.01$ are pre-set parameters, and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \sim N(0,1)$ follow the normal distribution IID. Recall that in the original Heston Model formulation, there is a condition (known as the Feller condition) to make sure that the values under the square root is positive. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model#cite_note-Albr2007-3) for more info. But in this case, how can I ensure that the value of $\sigma$ to be positive?

Comment: The 'discretization' is obviously unusable not only because it breaks down at negative square roots, but because it uses huge time intervals too. There are a lot of papers on Heston simulations/SDE simulations, you may look them up.

Comment: @Snoop Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I was trying to reproduce the results from the paper, and this is what the paper used.

Comment: Then you should contact the authors as this scheme is not working, by the way you might ask this on this forum : https://quant.stackexchange.com/